# After updating xcode to 8.0 facing problems?

Tags: xcode

I have updated my xcode to 8.0 and trying to run a sample demo app. i am getting the messages in log file like that 3 or 4 times . whats happening ??

```
2016-09-20 21:09:39.807151 demo[34599:1708960] subsystem: 
com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1,
persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, 
 generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, 
 enable_private_data: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are OS Activity logs. You can disable this as so:

1. Goto **Project> Schemes > Edit Scheme**
2. In the window select **Run**
3. Add the the environment variable as follows
   [image]

Comment: Thanks It worked .. I didnot see any links regarding these things .Thats why erase the questn.. :)

Comment: Erase the question?

Comment: sorry "raise the question"